# Debian VirtualBox Guest - Common Files to Remove for Space Saving?

Tags: debian, filesystems, files, virtualbox

I have created a VirtualBox guest using debian-6.0.7-amd64. I am using it as a clone template to create Java work nodes, so my needs are pretty much limited to the JVM, networking, SSH and the basics needed to actually work on the box. When I picked install package categories on install, I deselected everything except "basics" and SSH. I want to shrink this guy as much as possible (though I will need some available file-space) and then use it to clone up a bunch of new instances as I need them.

My question is, can you suggest a set of files that would be included in this distro, that I could safely delete and most likely not need for everyday support of what amounts to a JVM ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is not windows, there's no working way to cut `a great deal` of disk space from your system installation.

What you can do, is list all installed packages, and decide which one can be gone,

i.e `dpkg --list | less`

And you remove it through `apt-get remove XX`

And you're unlikely to find much space to save.